# SQL return count between occurence based on date range

Tags: sql

I'm trying to return a count of ID occurrences based on a date range and group by between two (occurrence) values.

The data is simple like this:

```
Date | ID
```

The result I am trying to accomplish looks like this:

```
DateRange | Occurrence-Count-1to2-Times | Occurrence-Count-3to5-Times | Occurrence-Count-6to10-Times | Occurrence-Count-Over10-Times
```

The Occurrence Count is how many times an ID shows between the two values. e.g. between 1 and 2 times (according to the date range specified).

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers. But I see a pivot in your future.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do two levels of aggregation:

```
select date, 
       sum(case when cnt <= 2 then 1 else 0 end) then times_1_2,
       sum(case when cnt > 2 and cnt <= 5 then 1 else 0 end) then times_3_5,
       . . .
from (select date, id, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by date, id
     ) di
group by date;
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "date range", but you can define the range in the subquery and use that for aggregation in both the subquery and the outer query.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after! I just need to sort through the date range now so it groups by my entire date range and not by day.

Comment: I removed the second grouping of the date and that solved the date range obstacle. Thanks Gordon Linoff !